# Make a query from a string in mongodb, python3

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to make query in mongodb where I don't know how many variables I have from the beginning. 
You get an array with variables(strings) and then mongo should return via the $or operator so there are no duplicates.

```
def findRecipes(IngredientsHome):
#Query and return all the alternatives

arrayCompleteSearch = [];
if len(IngredientsHome) > 1:
    #theHardStuuff
    #Create the query based on ingredientsarray
    argsCount = len(IngredientsHome)
    argsFunction = "";
    for i in range(0, len(IngredientsHome)):
        if i < (len(IngredientsHome)-1):
            argsFunction += ("{"+'"_Ingredients":' + '"' + IngredientsHome[i] + '"' "}, ")
        else:
            argsFunction += "{" + '"_Ingredients":' + '"' + IngredientsHome[i] + '"' + "}"
```

if I then do like this

```
print("coll.find({" + '$or' + ':' + '[' + argsFunction + ']' "})")
```

the commandline will print(not execute) the command i want to do in mongodb but I don't know how to make it work in mongo and return the results to an array. I am using pymongo and there i don't if it's possible to use a string as a full query. In sql I could put the whole "query" as a string `"SELECT * FROM ..."` while pymongo need : outside the string, more like `coll.find({"String":"String"})`. Is there a similar method or another way to make this query when I don't know how many expressions I have from the beginning in my mongodb query?

Comment: Are you trying to get the string in return or do you have to perform actual MongoDB query?

Comment: I have to do a MongoDB query. I need results from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing your query as a string, use PyMongo methods to query your database, for example:

```
coll.find({'_Ingredients': IngredientsHome[i]})
```

or you can pass the Python list and use `$in` in your query:

```
coll.find({'_Ingredients': {'$in': IngredientsHome}})
```

[Read more about how to use PyMongo here.](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I don't know how many parameters  I have from the beginning. I don't know if i should ma a query on IngredientsHome[1], IngredientsHome[2] and IngredientsHome[3] or just 2 IngredientsHome. If i just loop and make a new query everytime I will end up with multiples duplicates. 1 recipe contains multiples ingredients so the same recipe will come up multiple times.

Comment: @NotUser9123 Updated my answer!